# I am trying to index a request.css inside of my webscraper in python. But it does not work

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using scrapy when webscraping in Python and I am writing here because I want to figure out how I can for-loop through all values in a smart way.

I am trying with the logic below but seems to not work as I want it to...

```
products = category.css("div.offer-category__body > div.offer-category__item")
for i in lengthproduct:
    img = products(i).css("div.offer-type__image > img::attr(data-original)").extract_first()
```

Do you have any good tips of how I should loop through the elements and pick up all the values I want?
I am trying to webscrape this website:
https://www.ica.se/butiker/nara/bjurholm/ica-nara-westmans-livs-231/butikserbjudanden/

But if you want to try the full code then you will need to insert this URL: https://www.ica.se/butiker/ into the a notebook and call the notebook "URLs to be scrapped.txt"

The full code is attached below:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import csv

with open("URLs To be Scrapped.txt") as f:
    URLs = f.readlines()


class Playbook(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "PostcodesSpider"

custom_settings = {
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    'FEED_URI': 'DataFinal.csv',
}

script = """
function main(splash, args)
    splash.private_mode_enabled = false
    splash:go(args.url)
    splash:wait(2)
    splash:set_viewport_full()
    return splash:html()
end
"""

def start_requests(self):
    for url in URLs:
        yield SplashRequest(url=url.strip(),
                            callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True,
                            headers={
                                'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, "
                                              "like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
                            },
                            endpoint="execute", args={"lua_source": self.script, }
                            )

def parse(self, response):
    stores = response.css("div.store-card-content > div:nth-of-type(2) > a:last-of-type::attr(href)").extract()
    for store in stores:
        yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.ica.se/" + store.strip(),
                             callback=self.parse2, dont_filter=True,
                             headers={
                                 'USER-AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, "
                                               "like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
                             }, )

def parse2(self, response):
    storeName = response.css("h1.store-heading::text").extract_first()
    categories = response.css("section.offer-category")
    
    
    for category in categories:
        categoryName = category.css("header.offer-category__header::text").extract_first()      
        products = category.css("div.offer-category__body > div.offer-category__item")
                       
        print("test")
        lengthproduct=len(products)
        print(lengthproduct)
        for i in lengthproduct:
            img = products(i).css("div.offer-type__image > img::attr(data-original)").extract_first()
           

            yield {
                "Store": storeName.strip(),
                "Category": categoryName.strip(),
                "Image": img,
               
            }

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(Playbook)
process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you're trying to loop over an integer with the line `for i in lengthproduct:` which should not work, since for loops require [iterables](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module2_EssentialsOfPython/Iterables.html#Iterables). To write a for loop that would return values from 0 to `lengthproduct` you can use the [range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges) function.

However, in this case I think you just want to iterate over every found product.
You can do that as follows:

```
for product in products:
    img = product.css("div.offer-type__image > img::attr(data-original)").get()
```